# Почему мне выдаёт "Program1.pas(10) : Встречено 'else', а ожидался оператор" в моей программе?

Tags: строки, pascal, pascalabc.net, системы-счисления

```
Program PerevodChisla;

    procedure Dec2Bin(var decim : integer; binar: string);
begin
  readln(Decim);
  if decim > 0 then 
     begin
     if Decim mod 2 = 0 then 
         binar := Binar + '0';
       else 
         binar := Binar + '1';
     end;
     
  end;

var
a:integer;
s:string; 

begin
readln(a);
Dec2Bin(a, s);
writeln(s);
end.
```

Comment: следующий вопрос будет, почему программа не работает...

Comment: Не нужно после получения ответа модифицировать вопрос так, что перестает быть видна исходная проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите точку с запятой после

```
binar := Binar + '0'
```

Вы же не делаете многострочный блок `begin .. end`

Только вот все равно не сработает верно - хотя бы потому, что строку вы передаете без `var`, так что после выхода из функции переданная строка останется неизменной...

А вообще - непонятно, что вы реально хотите. По сути вы считываете какое-то число, выбрасываете, читаете новое число и *пытаетесь* вывести `0` или `1` в зависимости от его четности. Это точно то, что вы хотели?

Comment: Я хочу написать программу, которая будет преобразовывать десятичные числа в двоичные. Ошибка с else ушла, но моя цель не исполнена

Comment: https://ideone.com/adTQ1g

Comment: @Harry достаточно `var binar: string;` размер указывать не нужно

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Охотно поверю - последний раз на Pascal я программировал в 1990-х...